# Unable to retrieve a custom component resource from ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, resources, custom-controls

I keep getting a ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException when I try to pull out my "JrTaskbarIcon" from my ResourceDictionary.

This is the original code that throws this exception:

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private JrTaskbarIcon taskbarIcon;
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        taskbarIcon = (JrTaskbarIcon) FindResource("taskbarIcon");
    }
    protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        taskbarIcon.Dispose();
        base.OnExit(e);
    }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application 
    x:Class="JobRequestApprovalNotifier.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="TaskbarIcon">
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="JrTaskbarIcon.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

**JrTaskbarIcon.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:JobRequestApprovalNotifier">
    <local:JrTaskbarIcon
        x:Key="taskbarIcon"
        x:Name="taskbarIcon"
        ToolTipText="Job Requests"
        IconSource="/JobRequestApprovalNotifier;component/resources/notification.ico"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**JrTaskbarIcon.cs : Inherits TaskbarIcon from Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification**

```
public class JrTaskbarIcon : TaskbarIcon
{
    private BackgroundWorker jrMonitorThread;

    public JrTaskbarIcon()
    {
        jrMonitorThread = new BackgroundWorker();
        jrMonitorThread.WorkerReportsProgress = false;
        jrMonitorThread.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        jrMonitorThread.DoWork += JrScan;
        jrMonitorThread.RunWorkerCompleted += JrScanComplete;

        jrMonitorThread.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void JrScan(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void JrScanComplete(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I know the error occurs on line:

```
taskbarIcon = (JrTaskbarIcon) FindResource("taskbarIcon");
```

in the App.xaml.cs file.  I cannot for the life me retrieve this object.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Kyle.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer, unfortunately it took a few hours of banging my head against my desk, but alas, I have finally got it working.

I am not really sure of the syntax to be used to call FindResource() since nothing I tried there worked.  However, I was able to get a reference to "Resources" and from there, get the first MergedDictionary in the list, pull out its Values ICollection object and pull out the first item in it.

Here is the updated App.xaml.cs file:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private JrTaskbarIcon taskbarIcon;
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        ResourceDictionary resources = (ResourceDictionary) FindResource("TaskbarIcon");
        taskbarIcon = (JrTaskbarIcon) resources.MergedDictionaries[0]
                                               .Values
                                               .OfType<object>()
                                               .FirstOrDefault();
    }
    protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        taskbarIcon.Dispose();
        base.OnExit(e);
    }
}
```

As you can see, instead of using:

```
taskbarIcon = (JrTaskbarIcon) FindResource("taskbarIcon");
```

I am getting taskbarIcon by using:

```
    ResourceDictionary resources = (ResourceDictionary) FindResource("TaskbarIcon");
    taskbarIcon = (JrTaskbarIcon) resources.MergedDictionaries[0]
                                           .Values
                                           .OfType<object>()
                                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: _"I found the answer"_ -- no, not really. You've found a way to work around whatever bug you've got. But you haven't really _solved_ the original problem. Fact is, the code you posted in your question should work. It _does_ work when I compile and run basically the same thing (I don't have `Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification`, whatever that is, so my own custom class has to stand in for your `JrTaskbarIcon` class). If you want a _real_ answer, please fix your question so that it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.